# Does React send over its entire public directory contents?

Tags: reactjs

I was wondering about how React's public directory works. Will the entire public directory be sent to the client or just the files that are being used?

Answer (score 0):

Only the files which are requested by the user (either XHR, Fetch or directly) are actually transferred over the network.

But all the files which are in the public directory are available. So if the user wants to fetch them via the URL they can get the content of them.

Answer (score 0):

React is front-end, it doesn't have authority to decide what the server does or does not share. That's the task of the server.